# How can I send an email using an adaptive card with button in bot framework composer?

Tags: botframework, bots, bot-framework-composer

I created an adaptive card with an action.sumbit to send an email, but I can't get it to send the email.

I leave you the adaptive card.

```
 {
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.0",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "size": "large",
      "weight": "bolder",
      "text": "MAil"
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "data": {
        "myName": "asds",
        "myEmail": "ASASAD@fadff.com"
      },
      "title": "Send Email"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send an email from within Composer by using the 'Send an HTTP request' action located under 'Access external resources'. [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), and possibly other services depending on who you use and what they offer, has an API endpoint you can utilize for sending an email thru via a `POST` request.

You can experiment with the API by visiting the link I included above. Reference docs regarding the REST API are available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mail-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0).

The basic setup is, upon the user clicking submit on the adaptive card, the HTTP `POST` call will be made to the API sending the generated email.