# How to send form data to email with Bot Framework Composer

Tags: bots, botframework, bot-framework-composer

I have a form created on Bot Framework Composer and I would like to know if anyone ever try to send the data from the form to an email.

Thank you

Comment: Could you perhaps be a bit more specific on what you've built and what exactly you want to send? Perhaps the [email channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-email?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) might serve your needs?

Comment: The question is related to Bot FrameWork Composer where I have an adaptive card and this card has a Submit button. So, as the documentation is really poor, I would like to know if anyone has ever make the Submit button to work sending the info of the form to an email address. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to make a call to an outside service to accomplish this.

This question was asked before and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66892813/how-can-i-send-an-email-using-an-adaptive-card-with-button-in-bot-framework-comp). Perhaps this will help you?